# What is the range of ephemeral ports on mac?

Tags: macos, tcp

I am trying to benchmark a web framework and read that not having enough free ephemeral ports can falsify the results. Unfortunately, I haven't found what the ephemeral port range is on my mac, or how to display it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Benchmarkers, Beware the Ephemeral Port Limit](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129235834/http://danielmendel.github.io/blog/2013/04/07/benchmarkers-beware-the-ephemeral-port-limit/), a good article on the topic, addressing also the issue of TIME_WAIT for ephemeral ports. The port range on macOS can be displayed by:

```
>> sysctl net.inet.ip.portrange.first net.inet.ip.portrange.last
net.inet.ip.portrange.first: 49152
net.inet.ip.portrange.last: 65535
```

Comment: In addition, to set the value, simply use `sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.portrange.first=xxx`

Comment: if i run ✗ sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.portrange.last=91935 then i got:
net.inet.ip.portrange.last: 65535 -> 65535

Comment: @Scott混合理论 late reply but it is not possible to have a port higher than 65535, reduce portrange.first instead